# What is the function of "Ну и" at the start of conversation?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения, междометие

> **Ну и** денек выдался в минувшую субботу!

I assume these two words are not to be interpreted literally as "Well and". When do you use "Ну и" like this at the start of conversation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>*By Alone-zee's request i trasfer here my comments made in response to identical sub-question [in another thread](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/16185/7674)*</sup>

**ну и** is an emphatic compound interjection in exclamations expressing negative emotions or attitude, it functions as the English **what a...; such a...; so...** but only in a negative context, e.g.

> ***Ну и*** погодка сегодня! - ***What a*** terrible weather we have today!
>
> ***Ну и*** дурак ***же*** ты!/***Ну*** ты ***и*** дурак! - You're ***such a*** fool!
>
> ***Ну*** ты ***и*** загнул!/***Ну*** ***и*** загнул ***же*** ты! - You're ***so*** exaggerating!
>
> [***Ну и*** видок у тебя,
>   Шарапов!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ogIxmP5hwA4) - You have ***such
>   a*** terrible look, Sharapov!

`- Could it be that this "и" is a particle for emphasis that often precedes a verb?`

I doubt that. **ну и** goes not only with verbs and rather to a lesser extent with verbs, and it doesn't follow some previous statement for confirmation or reinforcement, it is perfectly autonomous and self-contained.

Check these examples of usage with a verb:

**`1.`** ***Ну*** ты ***и*** пишешь! <sup>*(a comment about quality of handwriting)*</sup> - You have ***such an*** awful handwriting! <sup>*(characters are either too small, illegible, ugly, don't meet some arbitrary requirements or something else etc)*</sup>

VERSUS

in a dialogue:

**`2.`**
-Зачем я это пишу? - Why am i even writing this?
-Тебе сказали писать?  - Have you been told to write this?
-Да. - Yes.
-Ну / Вот / Ну вот ты ***и*** пишешь. - So that's why you're writing.

Note that in the second example the phrase doesn't end with exclamation mark, it would be inappropriate here because it's not an exclamation.

Comment: _Ну и отлично!_

Comment: semantics of **ну и** in *Ну и отлично!* (also *Ну и ладно! Ну и не надо! Ну и иди!*) is different from that in *Ну и денёк...!* and so merits its own question and explanation

Answer (score 4):

This could be translated as

> What a ... !

The sentence above:

> What a [wonderful / terrible / ...] day was on saturday!